# validar datos con sql de 2 tablas

Tags: mysql

tengo 2 tablas las cuales tengo que validar.

la primera tabla (tabla1) cuenta con los siguientes datos

| id | nombre | diagnostico | fecha_nac |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan | H123 - en mal estado | 15-01-1990 |
| 2 | Carlos | K23.11 - en buen estado | 20-11-1970 |

la segunda tabla (tabla2) con los datos a validar es la siguiente

| codigo_diag | descripcion | rango_edad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| h123 | en mal estado | 25 AND 30 |
| k23.11 | en buen estado | 0 AND 5 |

como con una consulta sql puedo validar que el diagnostico este contenido en la tabla 2 y a su vez la edad corresponda al rango de edad respecto a la fecha de nacimiento de la tabla 1?

para extraer el código del campo diagnostico (tabla 1) uso lo siguiente.
`TRIM(SUBSTRING(diagnostico,1,LOCATE('-',diagnostico,1)-1))`

para calcular la edad al día de hoy uso lo siguiente.
`YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(fecha_nac) +IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d') > DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nac,'%m-%d'), 0 , -1 )`

Comment: Me parece que los datos en las tablas no estan bien estructurados.  En la primera tabla deberias tener una columna con el codigo del diagnositco y otra con la descripcion.  En la segunda tabla deberias tener dos columnas para delimitar el rango edad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque es evidente que ambas tablas posee debilidades estructurales que impiden una adecuada interrelación, así como también que el rango de edad que debería estar comprendido por dos columnas (min y max), el siguiente query permite hacer lo que requieres:

```
SELECT
pacientes.nombre,
diagnostico.codigo_diag,
diagnostico.descripcion,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(diagnostico.rango_edad,' ',1) AS rango_min,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(diagnostico.rango_edad,' ',3),' ',-1) AS rango_max,
YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(fecha_nac) +IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d') > DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nac,'%m-%d'), 0 , -1 ) AS edad,
CASE WHEN 
(YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(fecha_nac) +IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d') > DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nac,'%m-%d'), 0 , -1 ) >= SUBSTRING_INDEX(diagnostico.rango_edad,' ',1)) AND (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(fecha_nac) +IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d') > DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nac,'%m-%d'), 0 , -1 ) <= SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(diagnostico.rango_edad,' ',3),' ',-1)) THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END AS en_rago
FROM pacientes
INNER JOIN diagnostico
 ON TRIM(SUBSTRING(pacientes.diagnostico,1,LOCATE('-',pacientes.diagnostico,1)-1)) = diagnostico.codigo_diag
```

Vale mencionar que hago uso exacto de esto:

> para extraer el código del campo diagnostico (tabla 1) uso lo
> siguiente. TRIM(SUBSTRING(diagnostico,1,LOCATE('-',diagnostico,1)-1))
>
> para calcular la edad al día de hoy uso lo siguiente.
> YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(fecha_nac) +IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d') >
> DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nac,'%m-%d'), 0 , -1 )

Asi mismo, se emplea el uso de [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) y [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html)

Comment: muchísimas gracias, me ha servido un montón... corregiré los detalles para no hacer el calculo en la consulta. pero lo que me envías funciona perfecto

Comment: por nada, fue un gusto ayudarte. Como sugerencia te diría que evalúes crear función para calcular la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento y crear una vista con lo campos que necesitas, así el query se vería mas limpio.

Comment: el cambio que realice a nivel de consulta sql, fue cambiar el CASE en el WHERE, así solo mostrara los resultados que cumplan con el criterio a evaluar.